# How to read a txt file in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a notebook in android.My txt file can has lots of line. But this code only reads first line.

For example while I am writing to text file, if I press to "Enter" button , it reads until where I press enter

```
public String readFile(String fileName){
            String text="";
            String line="";
    try {
        File file=new File(this.getFilesDir(),fileName+".txt");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);

        for(;;){

            line=br.readLine();

            if(line!=null){
                text+=line+ "\n\r";
            }break;

            }

            br.close();
            isr.close();
            fis.close();



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return text;
}
```

Comment: Your code is a mess. You have a for-loop with an empty head which breaks on it's first run (that is what the `break` does). You are probably missing an else block. Your code can be optimized to `while((line = reader.readLine() != null){ [Your logic here...] } [Close streams here..]`. Either way, your code is improperly formatted, try googling for Java code style.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (br.readLine() != null) {
text+=br.readLine();
}
```